# Is it possible to import records in bulk into a SharePoint List which contains metadata columns with Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online

In my previous questions i have asked if it where possible to add records in bulk into a sharepoint list which contain metadata columns. The response was NO because the values of the metadata columns are automatically created by Sharepoint. Is it possible to do this with Powershell.?

Greetings,

Peter Kiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample script for your reference:

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "<SiteURL>"
$ListName = "<ListName>"
$CSVFilePath = "C:\Temp\BulkImportItems.csv"
 
#Function to get Lookup ID from Lookup Value
Function Get-LookupID($ListName, $LookupFieldName, $LookupValue) {
    #Get Parent Lookup List and Field from Child Lookup Field's Schema XML
    $LookupField =  Get-PnPField -List $ListName -Identity $LookupFieldName
    [Xml]$Schema = $LookupField.SchemaXml
    $ParentListID = $Schema.Field.Attributes["List"].'#text'
    $ParentField  = $Schema.field.Attributes["ShowField"].'#text'
    $ParentLookupItem  = Get-PnPListItem -List $ParentListID -Fields $ParentField | Where {$_[$ParentField] -eq $LookupValue} | Select -First 1 
    If($ParentLookupItem -ne $Null)  { Return $ParentLookupItem["ID"] }  Else  { Return $Null }
}
 
Try {
    #Connect to the Site
    Connect-PnPOnline -URL $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
 
    #Get the data from CSV file
    $CSVData = Import-CSV $CSVFilePath
 
    #Get the List to Add Items
    $List = Get-PnPList -Identity $ListName
     
    #Get fields to Update from the List - Skip Read only, hidden fields, content type and attachments
    $ListFields = Get-PnPField -List $ListName | Where { (-Not ($_.ReadOnlyField)) -and (-Not ($_.Hidden)) -and ($_.InternalName -ne  "ContentType") -and ($_.InternalName -ne  "Attachments") }
      
    #Loop through each Row in the CSV file and update the matching list item ID
    ForEach($Row in $CSVData) {
        #Frame the List Item to update
        $ItemValue = @{}            
        $CSVFields = $Row | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select -ExpandProperty Name
        #Map each field from CSV to target list
        Foreach($CSVField in $CSVFields) {
            $MappedField = $ListFields | Where {$_.InternalName -eq $CSVField}
            If($MappedField -ne $Null) {
                $FieldName = $MappedField.InternalName
                #Check if the Field value is not Null
                If($Row.$CSVField -ne $Null) {
                    #Handle Special Fields
                    $FieldType  = $MappedField.TypeAsString 

                    #People Picker Field
                    If($FieldType -eq "User" -or $FieldType -eq "UserMulti")  {
                        $PeoplePickerValues = $Row.$FieldName.Split(",")
                        $ItemValue.add($FieldName,$PeoplePickerValues)
                    }

                    #Lookup Field
                    ElseIf($FieldType -eq "Lookup" -or $FieldType -eq "LookupMulti") {
                        $LookupIDs = $Row.$FieldName.Split(",") | ForEach-Object { Get-LookupID -ListName $ListName -LookupFieldName $FieldName -LookupValue $_ }                
                        $ItemValue.Add($FieldName,$LookupIDs)
                    }
                    Else {
                        #Get Source Field Value and add to Hashtable
                        $ItemValue.Add($FieldName,$Row.$FieldName)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Write-host "Adding List item with values:"
        $ItemValue | Format-Table
        #Add New List Item
        Add-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Values $ItemValue | Out-Null
    }
}
Catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

**Note**: You will need to pre-construct the list with all columns with same names with the CSV file, and also the term set with all terms pre-created in the site.

Reference: [SharePoint Online: Import CSV File into SharePoint List using PowerShell.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/09/import-csv-file-to-sharepoint-list-using-powershell.html)